# How to avoid forgetting to define operator== in subclasses?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class and define a operator== on it. And `B` is a subclass of `A` and I forget to define `operator==` on `B`. Then `A::operator==` is used on comparing `B` and usually this gives an unexpected results. Any good method to avoid such "forget"? I add an example to clarify my question.

```
class A
{
public:
    bool operator==(const A& rhs) const
    {
        return i == rhs.i;
    }

    int i
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int j;
}

B b1, b2;
b1.i = 1; b1.j = 2;
b2.i = 1; b1.j = 3;
bool b = (b1 == b2); // will be true
```

Comment: Don't know if that's good, but you could use `template<class T> bool operator==(const T& rhs) const { static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>{}, "invalid argument type"); static_assert(std::is_same<A, T>{}, "define your own operator=="); return /* something */; }`

Comment: Add an equality check in the unit tests you're presumably writing for each of your classes?

Comment: make it pure virtual?

Comment: Just for the laughs: `struct S { struct yes_I_did_define_my_own_eq_operator{}; S(yes_I_did_define_my_own_eq_operator){} }; struct A : virtual S { bool operator==(const A& rhs) const; A() : S(yes_I_did_define_my_own_eq_operator) {} };` any derived class must call the constructor of `S`. (an compiler-checked comment ;)

Comment: @DyP yea that would definitely increase the wtf factor during code review

Comment: A better version than my original suggestion permits implicit conversions: `static_assert(is_base_of<A, T>{} || is_convertible<T, A>{}, "invalid argument type"); static_assert(not is_base_of<A, T>{} || is_same<A, T>{}, "define your own operator==");`

Comment: *I forgot a pair of `{}` in my "just for the laughs" comment : `A() : S(yes_I_did_define_my_own_eq_operator{}) {}`*

Comment: @user1899020 I've added some more to my answer. See if that helps.

Comment: I help there is an compiler warning ID for this. But not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allowing implicit conversions for [greatwolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234175/greatwolf)'s great [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18777820/420683) is a bit tricky:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace stuff
{

    template<class T, class U>
    bool operator== (const T &lhs, const U &rhs)
    {
        using namespace std;
        static_assert(is_convertible<T, U>{} || is_convertible<U, T>{},
                      "invalid argument type");
        static_assert
        (
               is_same<T, U>{}
            || ( not is_base_of<T, U>{} && not is_base_of<U, T>{})
            , "use explicit casts to compare derived to base class types"
        );
        return is_equal(lhs, rhs);
    }

    template<class T>
    bool is_equal(T const&, T const&)
    {
        // force compile-time failure when instantiating
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, void>{},
          "no free is_equal function for these argument types available");

        return false;
    }

    class A
    {
    private:
        int i;

        friend bool is_equal(A const& lhs, A const& rhs)
        { return lhs.i == rhs.i; }

    public:
        A(int p_i) : i(p_i) {}
    };

    class B : public A
    {
        int j;

    public:
        B(int p_i, int p_j) : A(p_i), j(p_j) {}
    };

    class C : public A
    {
    private:
        int j;

        friend bool is_equal(C const& lhs, C const& rhs)
        {
            return    is_equal(static_cast<A const&>(rhs),
                               static_cast<A const&>(lhs))
                   && lhs.j == rhs.j;
        }

    public:
        C(int p_i, int p_j) : A(p_i), j(p_j) {}
    };

}

struct D
{
    operator stuff::C() const
    {
        return stuff::C(1, 42);
    }
};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    stuff::A a(1), aa(1);
    stuff::B b(1, 42), bb(1, 42);
    stuff::C c(1, 42), cc(1, 42);

    D d;

    // commented lines invoke compilation failures
    std::cout << "a == aa: " << (a == aa) << std::endl;
  //std::cout << "a == b : " << (a == b ) << std::endl;
  //std::cout << "b == bb: " << (b == bb) << std::endl;
  //std::cout << "a == c : " << (a == c ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c == cc: " << (c == cc) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d == c : " << (d == c ) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you could try is put `A` in a namespace, create `operator ==` as a template non-member also in that namespace and let ADL take care of it.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace stuff {
class A
{
};

class B : public A {};

template <typename T>
bool operator == (const T &lhs, const T &rhs)
{
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  return &lhs == &rhs; // <-- replace this with something real
}

}

struct C {};

int main()
{
  stuff::A a, aa;
  stuff::B b, bb;
  C c, cc;

  b == bb;
  aa == a;

  aa == cc; // error: no match for "operator==" stuff::A and C
  b == a;   // error: no match for "operator==" stuff::B and stuff::A
}
```

**Edit:** For your edited example where you want the equality check to compare each part of the class with the other respective corresponding part, DyP's suggestion can work. For example:

```
// same as before
// ...
class A
{
public:
  bool is_equal(const A &rhs) const { return i == rhs.i; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  bool is_equal(const B &rhs) const { return A::is_equal(rhs) && (j == rhs.j); }
};

template <typename T>
bool operator == (const T &lhs, const T &rhs)
{
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  return lhs.is_equal(rhs);
}
```

Now comparing this again in the using code:

```
// ...
b.i = 1, bb.i = 1;
b.j = 1, bb.j = 42;
cout << boolalpha << (b == bb) << '\n';
b.j = 42;
cout << (b == bb) << '\n';

a.i = 2, aa.i = 3;
cout << (aa == a) << '\n';
```

outputs:

```
bool stuff::operator==(const T&, const T&) [with T = stuff::B]
false
bool stuff::operator==(const T&, const T&) [with T = stuff::B]
true
bool stuff::operator==(const T&, const T&) [with T = stuff::A]
false
```

Comment: @user1899020 Argument-Dependent (name) Lookup

Comment: Interesting solution, though the error message is not very nice, even with clang++: "error: invalid operands to binary expression ('stuff::A' and 'stuff::B')  `a == b;` [...] note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('stuff::A' vs. 'stuff::B')" (also, it doesn't allow implicit conversion)

Comment: @user1899020 The idea is to setup the template to only be instantiable with both arguments being the same type. The namespace is there to keep it from erroneously trying to instantiate it for all classes you create.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have equality comparison in a class hierarchy? In many cases, this indicates a problem with the design, with classes that don't properly behave like value types, but not properly like objects from a hierarchy either.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `operator==` in the case class a template and use a `static_assert` or concepts to constrain it to be called only with base class references. "Accidental" use of the operator with a derived class will fail to complete.

```
class A
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    bool operator==(const T& rhs) const
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, A>, "bad call of A::operator==");
        return i == rhs.i;
    }

    int i;
};
```